# how to allow RSS aggregators to use feeds available only for logged-in users?

Tags: django, authentication, rss

I want to have RSS feeds in my Django application, which should be
viewable only by a logged-in user. I want to allow users to add these
RSS feeds to all aggregators, so I would need something which would
work like this: supply the feed URL with a token, for example:
http://example.com/feed/rss&token=AeYQtFjQfjU5m  so that token will
cause the feed to be seen as if the user would be logged in.

Is there some library in Django which would provide such a
functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a hash of some unique property of the user... something like

```
md5("%s!%s" % (SECRET_KEY, user.username)).hexdigest()
```

PS - I didn't test this code but you get the idea

Comment: OK, thanks. Just two notes: if I "import md5" it results in TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Took me a while to find out I need 
md5.md5("%s!%s" % (SECRET_KEY, user.username)).hexdigest()

But then found out that this is depreceated, and since Python 2.5 one should use: 

 hashlib.md5("%s!%s" % (SECRET_KEY, user.username)).hexdigest()

or even:

 hashlib.sha512("%s!%s" % (SECRET_KEY, user.username)).hexdigest()

Comment: yeah that should start with `from hashlib import md5` =D

Answer (score 2):

You could generate  the token when creating a user for the first time. This way you can add the token to the feed when a user is logged in. Later when a RSS feed reader comes by your site for the user, you just load the user information for the user with that token.

Comment: that is basically security by obscurity, but at the same time it's the best possible solution, since RSS aggregators tend to have zero support for authentication

Comment: I didn't describe the way that you could generate the token. I would use some kind of randomly generated token, because it's easier to regenerate if it's compromised. Your solution would work to.